# Alexander–Briggs notations for the links or knots of $N^3_m$

Tags: general-topology, knot-theory, knot-invariants

We can use Alexander–Briggs notations for the links or knots. For example,

[image]

is three separate loops with no links.

And there are many other examples of Alexander–Briggs notations for three separate loops.

[image]

> Question 1: where can I find the Reference and Figures for **more complete lists for Alexander–Briggs notations and their corresponding graphs for three separate loops, i.e. with 
>   $$N^3_m$$ in Alexander–Briggs notations?** Here $3$ means 3 separate loops. And $N$ means the crossing numbers; $m$ is simply a counting of different types.

I am interested to know, for example,

> Question 2:  what is $4^3_1$? and what is $5^3_1$, $4^3_2$, $5^3_2$, $6^3_4$(?) if there is any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that Alexander-Briggs notation is generally reserved for **prime** links and so, for instance, $4_1^3$ is not usually written as any three component link with $4$ crossings (and no un-linked components) must be the connect sum of two Hopf links.

My copy of *Knots and Links* by Dale Rolfsen includes as an appendix the full list of prime $3$-component links with no un-linked components and up to $9$ crossings beginning at $6_1^3$ and ending at $9_{21}^3$. These links are enumerated using Alexander-Briggs notation. A bit of Googling may also find this information (I'm not sure if it would be right to link to copyrighted material).

The [Handbook of Knot Theory](http://pzacad.pitzer.edu/~jhoste/HosteWebPages/downloads/Enumeration.pdf) is a good survey article for questions on enumeration and classifications of knots and links.

Comment: thank you for the nice reply. Let me see. +1.