# The math notation of this links? (connect sum of Hopf links)

Tags: knot-theory, knot-invariants

We know the Hopf link owns the name of $2^2_1$ for Alexander–Briggs notations. (And there is another two component links is $4^2_1$.)

[image]

I learned that "$4^3_1$ is not usually written as any three component link with 4 crossings (and no un-linked components) must be the connect sum of two Hopf links." from [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/762123/alexanderbriggs-notations-for-the-links-or-knots-of-n3-m).

> **question: So how do we call this following three component links in Alexander–Briggs notations below?** Could it be $4^3_1$? Or what ever other notations we use to describe this links? Is this **connect sum of two Hopf links**? Can we write it as $2^2_1 \oplus 2^2_1$? So if there are sum of N Hopf links, can we denote $$\bigoplus_N 2^2_1 \;\;\;\;?$$

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to be careful when taking the connect sum of links as the operation is not well defined until you have specified which components are being connected together (we also need to consider orientation) For instance if we have three Hopf links $H_1, H_2, H_3$ with components $C_i^1,C_i^2$ of $H_i$, then $(H_1\#_{C_1^2,C_2^1}H_2)\#_{C_2^1,C_3^1}H_3$ and $(H_1\#_{C_1^2,C_2^1}H_2)\#_{C_2^2,C_3^1}H_3$ are not the same link$^*$  because the first can be disconnected into a trivial link with three components by removing a single component (the 'central' component $C_1^2$), whereas the second can not be similarly disconnected.

Note, the $\#_{C_i^j,C_{k}^{l}}$ notation I've used above is just my own notation - I don't know if there is a standard notation which means 'take the connect sum along the component $C_i^j$ of the left link and the component $C_k^l$ of the right link'.

It turns out that the connect sum of two Hopf links is invariant under a choice of components to connect (or even orientation of components) for pretty obvious diagramatic reasons so you can write $H_1\#H_2$ without confusion, as long as you don't then plan to take the connect sum of this with other links. As such, I think you would be fine in calling the link you have presented $2_1^2\#2_1^2$ - I don't know if this is standard notation and I am *not* an authoritative source on knot theory.

$^*$ *Note the second connect sum is done on different components of the link $H_1\#_{C_1^2,C_2^1}H_2$ at $C_2^1$ and $C_2^2$ respectively.*

Comment: Thanks Daniel, who will be the authoritative source on knot theory in your opinion?

Comment: There are dozens of well written books and hundreds of academics working in the area. I'm afraid it all depends on what part of knot theory you're interested in.

Comment: Here $H_1 \#_{C^2_1,C^1_2} H_2$,  at $C^1_2$ and $C^2_1$ respectively? Do you have a typo in the last sentence?

Comment: Can you guys please helping me on this, too? I am not sure your answer Daniel.  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/764925/notations-for-the-direct-sum-of-links

Comment: @Idear I'm pretty sure that's right. The link $L=H_1\#_{C_1^2,C_2^1}H_2$ has three components connected in a chain, we then connect $H_3$ to this chain in two ways. The first way by connecting it on the 'center' component $C_2^1$ (which is the same as the component $C_1^2$ now because of the previous connect sum) of the chain $L$, and the second way connecting it to the 'end' component of the chain $L$ at $C_2^2$. I apologise if the notation is sloppy - I couldn't think of a nicer way of writing these operations concisely and unambiguously.